# Call a main function from a second Python script using arguments determined in the second script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python function that takes 2 filenames and does some stuff with them. I want to write a wrapper script that will determine the filenames and call the main function of the original script with those arguments. I am very inexperienced with Python, does anybody know the simplest way to do this?

I'm working in a UNIX environment, not that that should make a difference.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: To clarify, I have a function called convert.py with a main function main () that takes two sys.argv inputs. I want these inputs to be determined in convert_wrapper.py as file1 and file2 and passed to convert.main() as those two sys.argv arguments. I currently have:

```
import convert
file1='abc'
file2='def'
convert.main(file1,file2)
```

but this gives me an error that I passed two arguments to a function that takes zero.

Comment: `import` the main function and call it the same way you'd call any other function. (I'm assuming by main function you mean a literal `def main` function, not an `if __name__ == "main":` condition or just naked code in the global scope)

Comment: Have you tried? You can define functions in modules, and call them with parameters. It's part of the standard [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat test.py

```
def main(a,b):
    return a+b
```

cat caller.py

```
from test import main

print main(5,3)
```

hope this helped..

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!